# Retrieving a PHP file using file_get_content(), cURL() or fopen() all return PHP code itself

Tags: php, curl, fopen, file-get-contents

I'm retrieving a PHP file using file_get_content(), cURL() or fopen() all return PHP code itself. It's not retrieving just the HTML code itself that PHP is outputting. How can I overcome this please?

It's basically generating an HTML newsletter preview for my customer that is generated from their CMS. However I want them to be able to copy and paste the HTML it generates into Mailchimp or such like. It just fetches the entire PHP source code though as well as the HTML :(

Hope you can help.

Thanks in anticipation.

Pete

Comment: Can you show some of the code you use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to read a local PHP file will return its source code, since its a "local" file, and is not parsed by the server.

If you wish to read the result of the PHP file you must request it from the server.
Meaning instead of doing:

```php
$data = file_get_contents('x.php');
```

You should be doing

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://mysite.com/path/x.php');
```

Which will be parsed in the server, and then returned to you.

Cheers! :)
Shai.

Comment: Hiya! Thanks, I've tried that too, but then the PHP code isn't shown but it's not executed either, meaning none of the dynamic content is displayed within the HTML template.

See what I mean? The HTML template (newsletter.php) pull in $_SESSION variables which it populates the HTML with. Is it because sessions somehow aren't preserved when calling the file via file_get_contents() ?

Comment: Its hard to say without seeing what your PHP file actually does. If your file requires session information you would have to use CURL and provide the data there, which is a bit trickier. It would be easier if you would upload the source to pastebin.com or such and than we can see whats what ;-)

Comment: Just a reminder to accept the answer if you feel it worked for you ;-) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in localhost. Try this one: $url = "http://localhost/box.php";

```
function isAllBoxContents($boxid,$pageNum)
{
$postdata = http_build_query( array('myBoxid' => "$boxid", 'isAllBoxContents' => "all",'pageNum' => "$pageNum",'innerReq' => true ));
$opts = array('http' =>    array( 'method'  => 'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => $postdata ));
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "http://localhost/box.php";
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context);
$cacheFileName = "isAllBoxContents".$boxid.$pageNum;
cacheMe($cacheFileName,$result);
}
```